# Finding the maximum value in an array but must be lower than a certain value

Tags: java

```
int array[] = new int[]{10, 11, 88, 2, 12, 9};

public static int getMax(int[] inputArray){ 
  int maxValue = inputArray[0];

  for(int i=1;i < inputArray.length;i++){ 
     if(inputArray[i] > maxValue){ 
        maxValue = inputArray[i]; 
     } 
  } 
  return maxValue; 
}
```

Is there any way to find the maximum value but lower than 88 in the array?

Comment: Wow that was fast~ Thanks for the quick reply~

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 8):

If you use `Integer`s you can do it using a `TreeSet`

```
Integer[] values = new Integer[]{10, 11, 88, 2, 12, 9};
NavigableSet<Integer> integers = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(values));

System.out.println(integers.lower(88));
System.out.println(integers.lower(2));
System.out.println(integers.lower(100));
```

prints out

```
12
null
88
```

The javadoc of [`NavigableSet.lower(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#lower(E)) says:

> Returns the greatest element in this set strictly less than the given element, or null if there is no such element.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Java8, you can use the [Streaming API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
int[] array = new int[]{10, 11, 88, 2, 12, 9};
final int limit = 88;
Optional<Integer> max = Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i < limit)
    .boxed().max(Comparator.naturalOrder());

System.out.println("Biggest element smaller than " + limit + " is " + max.get());
```

*Output:*

```
Biggest element smaller than 88 is 12
```

It does the following:

- converts the `int` array to a stream
- removes elements from the stream that are greater or equal to the specified limit (`.filter`)
- converts the stream to an `Integer` stream (`.boxed`)
- calculates the maximum using the natural order comparator (`.max`)

The key part of the stream is the `filter` where the elements that are greater than the limit are removed from the stream.

UPDATE: If the index is also needed

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(0, 11, 88, 2, 12, 9);
final int limit = 88;
IntStream.range(0, intList.size())
        .filter(i -> intList.get(i) < limit)
        .boxed().max(Comparator.comparing(intList::get))
        .ifPresent(resultIndex -> System.out.println("Index " + resultIndex + ", value " + intList.get(resultIndex)));
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the index of this `max` value in a single shot instead of the value?

Comment: @AyushKumar : Udated the post if you need the index too.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
public static int getMax(final int[] inputArray) {

    final int L = 88;

    int maxValue = inputArray[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (maxValue < L)
            break;
        maxValue = inputArray[i];
    }

    for (final int element : inputArray) {
        if (element >= L)
            continue;
        if (element > maxValue)
            maxValue = element;
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

Please be aware that the (some of the) other answers fail if `inputArray[0] >= 88`.